# Can swift international payment be retracted after being received?

Tags: international-transfer, swift

Is it possible for an international payment to be retracted once it’s arrived in the recipients account?

I received a payment from overseas buyer for a purchase and they sent me more than what I was expecting, an extra $17.  I don’t know whether they did this deliberately to be able to retract the payment on the basis of incorrect amount sent after I ship the goods.

I can see the payment in my account so it's not in transit.

Comment: Have you asked the sender? Could it be a currency conversion issue? What's the total amount involved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To your direct question: yes, there is a process to attempt to reverse international SWIFT payments, but it isn't one you can rely on happening. If the money is already visible in your account, reversal likely requires your consent.

As to why the amount extra was paid - the buyer may have intentionally been conservative and sent more of their local currency than what was needed when the funds were ultimately converted. If the fx rate changed over the course of the 2-3 days it probably took to arrive in your account, this becomes more likely.

Whether this is the answer largely depends on the amount being sent. If the purchase was in the ~$1000 range, 1.7% difference in received amount seems to be on the 'high end' of reasonable. If the purchase was in the $50 range, something else may have been going on - perhaps even error on the part of the buyer, when they sent funds.

Comment: Thanks, yeah the purchase was $773 but they sent $790. It doesn’t look like it was exchange rate related as I would have expected it to be a more uneven amount after conversion like $776.54638 as an example as opposed to 790 exact. The difference isn’t big just $17 so I was worried it was fishy. It was suggested when I looked online that if the bank made the error it could be retracted which still doesn’t play in my favour if they can move the funds out.

Comment: It could also be that they sent more because they expected a commission or fee that ended up not being charged

Comment: @Julia If you have any concern about whether funds could be revoked, you should call your own bank to ask. Without knowing the full situation I can't say for certain, but I suspect it is incredibly unlikely for the transaction to be 'reversible' in the way you are thinking. The lack of pennies to me doesn't imply fx isn't the cause, as the translating bank may simply cut off rounding as part of their standard practice; hard to say.